# Water Storage Scheduling

Tags: algorithm, optimization, workflow, scheduling

MIB's headquarter has *N* water tanks. Tank *i* can store at most *c<sub>i</sub>* units of water. Each tank has its own incoming and outgoing pipes.  Incoming pipe of tank *i* leaks water at rate *u<sub>i</sub>*, which means if we want to put 100 units of water into tank *i*, 100/(1 - *u<sub>i</sub>*) water will be consumed. Outgoing pipes are all perfect. Their capacities are *in<sub>i</sub>* and *out<sub>i</sub>*, which means the tank *i*'s incoming pipe can carry at most *in<sub>i</sub>* units of water in one unit of time (including leakage), and outgoing pipe can carry at most *out<sub>i</sub>* units of water in one unit of time.

The integer sequence *w<sub>t</sub>* (1 < t < T) represents how much water may be put into or has to be taken from this water storage system. For example (5, 3, -8, 10) means the system can intake at most 5, 3, and 10 units of water at the 1st, 2nd, and 4th time slots, and has to outlet 8 units of water at the 3rd time slot. It is called unfeasible if the amount of outlet water violates the requirement (violating intake requirement is fine).  The question is, given the parameters of each tank (*c<sub>i</sub>*, *u<sub>i</sub>*, *in<sub>i</sub>*, *out<sub>i</sub>*), and the sequence *w<sub>t</sub>*, weather it is feasible to satisfy all outlet requirement? All tanks are empty at time 0.

N < 10,000, T < 10,000

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like homework.  What have you tried?

Comment: @thursdaysgeek It's truly not a homework. I try to model it as a linear programming problem. However, it will take O((NT)^2) memory, just unfeasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, here is a scheme that doesn't work on its own because it ignores the constraints on maximum inflow and outflow rates, so it solves an easier problem.

The tricky bit here seems to be which tank to use when. It looks like tanks with lower values of Ui are better. If you take any sequence that fills a tank with a high value of Ui while there is a tank with a lower value of Ui that has space, then you can get a better sequence by filling the better tank first, and using the extra water when you would use the water you would otherwise put into the worse tank. Similarly, if you are extracting water from a bad tank when there is water in a good tank, you can get a better sequence by extracting the water from the good tank, which gives you the opportunity of filling it when you would otherwise fill the bad tank.

So it looks like when you fill a tank you want to fill the best tank available, and when you empty a tank you want to empty the best tank available. Given this - and assuming there aren't any restrictions you haven't mentioned, such as integer amounts of water in transfers - it looks like it is easy to find the best schedule in any given situation. So try this best schedule and if it doesn't work, nothing will.

The above doesn't work because I have ignored constraints. I have certainly ignored the inflow and outflow rates, and I am also assuming that you can use more than one tank at each step, which I suspect might not be the case.

There are other schemes that solve simpler problems - you could ignore all the constraints except the outflow rates and fill the tank with the highest outflow rate you can at each stage and provide water from the tank with the lowest outflow rate capable of meeting the demand.

These variants don't solve your problem, but if there is no solution when you ignore some of the constraints there is no solution to the original problem. This leads to a variant of branch and bound.

1) If a simple greed solution finds a good schedule, then the sequence is obviously solvable.

2) Try solving the easier problems. If any of them are unsolvable, there is no solution for this sequence.

3) Consider all possible choices for the first time step, calling yourself recursively to solve the resulting shorter sequences, starting with water in the tanks. As soon as any of them find a solution you can return with it. If you check all of them and they all say "no solution" then there is no solution.

Comment: Hi @mcdowella, thanks for your reply. The thing is that besides *ui*, we still need to consider *ci*. Suppose we have two tanks, *u1* = 0, *u2* = 0.5, *in1* = 10, *in2* = 10, and *c1* = 10, *c2* = 20. W = (10, 20). If we fill tank 1 first, then tank 1 will be full after time slot 1, and finally we will have 15 units of water (10 from tank1 and 5 from tank 2). In this case, fill tank 2 first is better.

Comment: OK - I over-simplified it and missed details (as usual!). However, I note that if you found that the over-simplified version of the problem was not solvable then the main problem isn't either. So I think you could try branch and bound on this and have edited my answer to describe this.